# How do I connect a local folder to an existing github repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I made a repo on my laptop. It has a project page on github.com.

I'm now working on my desktop computer. I manually copied over some files because I didn't think I would need every file from the repo (so I didn't clone the repo onto my desktop). How can I connect my desktop local folder with the existing repo so that I can push the files on my desktop to the repo (the desktop files are now the most recent versions of those files, since I stopped working from my laptop)

Comment: Clone the repo, and then copy paste the folder into it?

Comment: Do you want to work on the local folder desktop computer (which is not a local git repo?) and then push the changes from desktop to github?

Answer (score 62):

Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line:

```
# Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.
git init

# Add files
git add .

# Commit your changes
git commit -m "First commit"

# Add remote origin
git remote add origin <Remote repository URL>
# <Remote repository URL> looks like: https://github.com/user/repo.git

# Verifies the new remote URL
git remote -v

# Push your changes
git push origin master
```

And 2nd way as @evolutionxbox suggest you:

- Clone git repo
- Copy and paste into it
- Push your change at origin

If in any case git reject your push you can use `git push origin master --force`

**UPDATE** (10-23-2020):
Bear in mind that since October 1st, 2020, Github renamed the default repository from ***master*** to ***main*** https://github.com/github/renaming

Comment: @evolutionxbox As he has an existing repo already, have chance git reject push changes and recommend the `git pull` then he will need `--force` for push their new commits as I'm thinking.

Comment: Maybe `git fetch; git rebase origin/master; git push` rather than force push? Seems much safer.

Comment: considering this question was asked by newbie, the order of git commands you mentioned makes git reject your push.

Comment: @NitinNanda I have mention `--force` in case of reject. If you can improve the answer I will be happy to accept your changes.

Comment: @dvaergiller commands sequence is right. But consider that from 10-01-2020, for new repositories GitHub renamed the default 'master' branch to 'main'. So, it would look like this `git fetch; git rebase origin/main; git push`

Comment: How can we use `git diff` to see the changes before pushing? `git pull` suggests `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master` but I was not able to use it by replacing values and `git pull origin master` only shows the files changed without showing the diff.
This solution does not work for me, I downloaded a ZIP file of a GiHub repository, made changes and I get an error with `git push origin master`:
`! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs`
So I guess the only workaround is to clone the GitHub repository and replace the content.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a local repository in the temp-dir directory using:
   git clone  temp-dir
2. Go into the temp-dir directory.
3. do a git branch -a
4. Checkout all the branches that you want to copy from origin using git checkout branch-name

You are done